# Is dl_load_file called or not here?

Tags: perl

```
unless defined(&dl_load_file);
```

The above looks ambiguous to me but actually works .

How does Perl know whether or not to call `dl_load_file` here?

Answer (score 4):

It's just a special case in Perl's syntax.  If you have either `defined(&identifier)` or `defined &identifier`, it checks for the existence of a subroutine named `identifier` without calling it, even though `&identifier` would normally call the subroutine.

`defined &identifier()`, on the other hand, *does* call the subroutine and then test its return value.  The parens after identifier make it a function call.

Comment: and `goto &func` and `\&func`.

Comment: @ysth, so is `undef &func`.  I wasn't making a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a call - is just a check to see if that function is defined or not

Perl interpreter knows this with the help of [Symbol Tables](http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/08.symbol_tables.html)

Comment: How does Perl interpret know this?

Comment: I don't think it's enough to judge whether it's calling or not according to the context here.

Comment: It's not about calling or not - it's about its definition - is the function defined or not? the calling is done somewhere else :)